# How do I only get the room_type with the highest sum in my pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Im trying to find the room types per neighborhood group that have the highest sum. Which means I have to filter out all room_types per neighborhood that are not the highest sum. How do I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSsKI.png)

This is what I have so far. I just cant figure out how to get just room_type result (the one with the highest sum) per neighborhood_group.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC first aggregate `sum`, then sort by `sum` column and then drop duplicates by `neighborhood_group` and `room_type` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = (listing.groupby(['neighborhood_group','room_type'], as_index=False)
              .agg(**{'sum': ('reviews_per_month', 'sum')})
              .sort_values('sum', ascending=False)
              .drop_duplicates(['neighborhood_group','room_type']))
```